# How can I retrieve the friend_id column data of friend_user table , generated by friend model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

```
class Friend(models.Model):

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User) #following users

    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod

    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):

        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(

            current_user = current_user

        )

        friend.users.add(new_friend) 

    @classmethod

    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):

        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(

            current_user = current_user

        )

        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

This model has 2 tables

friends_friend having columns----- id, current_user_id

friends_friend_user having columns------id ,friend_id, user_id

Comment: How and where do you want to get this data?